# Run Function in original page from window.open javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, var

how can I run Function in original page from window.open

original_page.html

```
<div id="Processing" style="display:none;">
<button onclick="window.open("Processing_window.html")">open</button>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function submit_form() {    
          var upgradeForm = document.getElementById('upgradeForm');
          setTimeout("upgradeForm.submit()",3000); 
     } 

</script>
```

========

Processing_window.html

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function Processing_window() {  
        var doc = window.opener.document, Processing = doc.getElementById("Processing");
        Processing.style = '';
        submit_form();  //Here the problem
        window.close();
    } 
    setTimeout ("Processing_window()",5000); 
</script>
```

========

I went to run "submit_form();" funcion from Processing_window.html

Comment: Try parent.submit_form(); or window.opener.submit_form();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access functions from the opener, use `window.opener.functionName`, assuming both are in the same domain.

```
function Processing_window() {  
    var doc = window.opener.document, Processing = doc.getElementById("Processing");
    Processing.style = '';
    // Here's the solution
    window.opener.submit_form();  
    window.close();
} 
setTimeout ("Processing_window()",5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to HTML encode the quotation marks in the code in the attribute, or use apostrophes:

```
<button onclick="window.open('Processing_window.html')">open</button>
```

As long as the page that you open has the same origin (same server, same protocol), you can use the `opener` property to access the parent windows `window` object. There's where you find the reference to the function:

```
window.opener.submit_form();
```

Comment: The problem is not here
What I want is :
When closed the window is running function after 3 seconds
the function in the original page is not in the window page

Comment: @J7xx: What do you mean? The answer from Juan Mendes that you accepted has exactly the same code that I suggested.

Comment: I think he got distracted by your initial answer which was addressing a different problem and didn't see the second part, just like I also missed it and duplicated your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but not cross-domain. Only in the same domain.

```
<script>
function new_win_fun() {
var wind = window.open("Processing_window.html");
var upgradeForm = wind.document.getElementById("upgradeForm");
wind.setTimeout("upgradeForm.submit()",3000); 
}
</script>

<button onclick="new_win_func()">Run</button>
```

Comment: setTimeout("upgradeForm.submit()",3000);  i went to run "submit_form();" funcion after window.close and after 3000 S

Comment: run "wind.setTimeout("upgradeForm.submit()",3000); " after close window by the function in "Processing_window.html"